# Leaking from roof between a one-story sun room and main structure

Tags: leak, roof, waterproofing, roofing

After a big wind and rain,  today I found that it is leaking from the roof at the seam between this one-story sun room and the two-story main structure. This is the first time it leaked at this location since I moved here two years ago. However, there may have been temporary fixes, as a crack in the paint can be seen in the second picture.

Should I call a handyman or the company that installed our new roof two years ago? I suspect that the flashing between the sun room roof and the neighboring wall is broken.

[image: Roof_1]
[image: Roof_2]

Comment: Two year old roof should not leak, i do not know what the policy  of the roofing company is  but that would be the first place to start.

Comment: @AlaskaMan They have a 50 year old warranty on the shingles, but I doubt that the shingles are broken. I'll definitely call them but want to be educated first of things I should be aware of..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are signs of past water damage I would recommend opening the wall from the inside just below the leak to attempt to determine where the water is entering. Drywall repair is cheap versus the problems of moisture in the wall long term.
I just had a similar situation with damp drywall in a ceiling corner. In opening the wall there was a leak from flashing that wasn't properly installed that had been going on for years. The top double plates, the king stud along a window and the rafter base were all rotted away. It had been leaking for years without soaking through the drywall.
I would cut out just enough drywall to inspect the framing and roof area from the interior. Look at the framing members for any sign of moisture present or past. Water leaks sometime do strange things traveling along rafters, etc. before it becomes evident. As you get in there you may have to take out additional drywall as you track the leak.
Calling the roofers who did the installing is a good first step but until you determine the source any solution is only an educated guess.
**Edit**
As I said in comments: These leaks are usually easier to diagnose from the interior if you have possible access through drywall. If not, obviously, have the roofer check areas of the roof above the leak - even on the other side of the chimney chase. This is often a common problem area.

Comment: Yes, I very much want to avoid a temporary fix. It's the wood ceiling that's leaking, though, and the drywall is an internal wall against the two-story main structure. I can trace the water back up to the wood panels. I don't know what would be behind the wood panels, some plywood < waterproofing membrane < shingles? In my case, would it be something one can check from the outside?

Comment: I see. There will be sheathing of some sort behind the wood panels maybe even drywall. These issues are usually easier to diagnose and more accurately from the interior if you can access the area. However, good roofers can often pinpoint a problem from the roof with a fair degree of accuracy. In your pic it looks like you have a brick chimney to the right. I would have your roofer check around that area. Anywhere structures butt out on the roof impeding the flow of water down the roof line should be checked.

Comment: Good suggestions! The interesting part is that the leak is downstream from the chimney. In any case, my roofer took my call on Christmas day and would send someone here tomorrow! Kudos to the [Fitzgerald Roofing](https://goo.gl/maps/ZEabUKxTWz5cRs3MA).

Comment: Yes. I could see that it's downstream but, again, I've known leaks to travel 10 to 20 feet before they become visible. The leak is almost certainly above where you see it and may be on the other/up-roof side of the chimney.

Comment: Ah, got it! I missed the point.

Comment: The roofer came today and found a nail that was too low (not exactly sure what "low" means; probably not covered by the shingles from the row above it) and rusted. He caulked that nail, but also caulked around the chimney flashing.